# mysqli_connect errors - Packets out of order - Error while reading greeting packet - (HY000/2006) MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I have recently set up my raspberry pi as a web server on my local home network.  I have also installed mariaDB / MySQL server on the pi.  But when I try to connect to the mysql server using php from another device, I keep getting error messages.  (I know there are very similar issues posted here but nothing seems to work).

(When I run the code on the pi itself I don't receive any errors at all.)

Here is my test code:

```
<?php
//set up connection parameters
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";


//create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


//check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed");
}
echo "success";

//close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And the errors...

> Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=90

> mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=12660

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

Any advise on where to head next?

Comment: What did you put in `$servername`?

Comment: @Dharman the hostname of my pi (e.g. 'raspberrypi')

Comment: Exactly like that? Are you sure there are no other characters besides `raspberypi`? Try retyping it again

Comment: Where do you maintain the mapping of hostname to IP address?

Comment: @Dharman I have double-checked - it is still correct.  I don't manually map hostname to IP address.  If i type http://[hostname] into a browser, the example web page shows proving that the web server aspect is functioning - it is just connecting through php to the myqsl server which is the issue.

Comment: Then double check that MySQL server is really reachable via this hostname and this port. Maybe it is listening on a different port?